# Linux 100% cpu usage by unknown java process

Tags: linux

I set up a GitLab server, everything was ok and then accidentally server stop working and just shows the `502` error page which says `GitLab is taking too much time to respond.`

After checking the server I found this:
[image]

There are java processes that use all CPUs and it seems they are restarting and there is something want to run this java app at any cost.

I didn't install java on my machine. I have a `gitlab-runner` beside my GitLab server and I stopped `GitLab server` and `gitlab-runner`

How can I find the source of this java app and stop it?

The command is:

```
/usr/java/latest/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/data/apache-tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Xms512M -Xmx5120M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC -Djavax.net.debug=ssl -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /data/apache-tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/data/apache-tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/data/apache-tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/data/apache-tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data/apache-tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Comment: This likely has to do with how _your_ system has been configured and not anything to do with GitLab in particular. GitLab itself doesn't use Java or Tomcat.

Comment: Seconded sytech on his comment - this very likely isn't GitLab or its runner. It looks like you have a process that's running on tomcat, which is likely your culprit. If you look more into the java command it's executing, it may give you a jar name you can look into to debug the problem.

Comment: @sytech @patrick thank you, I agree with you but there is something strange about the process and that is the process is run by `git` user. Besides this, I check the java command and the paths command point to does not exist.

Comment: @AliMalek Maybe check your [`/sbin/init` configuration](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/installation_guide/s2-boot-init-shutdown-init) since it seems to be a child process of that. Also, if your runner is on the same server and uses a `shell` based executor that runs as the git user, you might be seeing processes started by GitLab jobs?